# Sending foreach output via email

Tags: powershell

I have a script that is checking mirror status of databases. Output in Powershell is fine, but when I try to send it via mail, I'm getting "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData" instead of data itself. I've tried to change it to Out-String but then I'm getting all results in one line. How this could be done to have formated output the same way as it is formated directly in PowerShell?

```
# rozszerzenie do obslugi 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") | Out-Null;


$mail_from = "xxx";
$mail_to = "xxx";
$mail_subject = "Status mirrorowanych baz";
$mail_encoding = "UTF8";
$mail_smtp = "xxx";

# lista serwerow
$list = @("SERVER01V", 
          "SERVER02V"
                );

$output = foreach($server in $list)
{
    $srv = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" $server;
    # pokaz tylko mirrorowane
    $databases = $srv.Databases | Where-Object {$_.IsMirroringEnabled -eq $true};
    Write-Output "<br>==================================<br>";  
    Write-Output $server;
    Write-Output "<br>==================================<br>";
    $databases | Select-Object -Property Name, MirroringStatus | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String;
    Write-Output "<br>";
}

$mail_body = $output;
Send-MailMessage -To $mail_to -From $mail_from -Subject $mail_subject -SmtpServer $mail_smtp -Encoding $mail_encoding -Body $mail_body -BodyAsHtml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently sending a HTML mail. As such line breaks won't matter. If you want line breaks in your mail you either need to use text format or replace line breaks with a `<br />` or something similar. It's probably going to be wise to have manually add `<br />` in your look to have a consistent pattern and replace.

Comment: Yeah, but the problem is in the line "$databases | Select-Object -Property Name, MirroringStatus | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String;". As the result of that, the mail looks like this:

`Name MirroringStatus ---- --------------- DB1 Synchronized DB2 Synchronized SSISDB Synchronized` Other strings as seperate lines and server name are in seperate lines.

Comment: The only other line you have is a static server name. Which is followed by a line break because you separator lines contain two line breaks (one before and one after them). If you're sending HTML you need to use HTML line breaks to display them. The line you're mentioned is unaware that you're sending HTML. As such there are no HTML line breaks added to it. You need to manually add them by using a replace. Even after that your output won't be as nice as you're not setting a mono space font for the HTML.

Comment: Ok, maybe I didn't clarify this enough. Line "$databases | Select-Object -Property Name, MirroringStatus | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String;" for server that have many databases in powershell looks good - it has a table form. But how this can be transform to a mail to look also like table (or just text formated with new lines)? I mean i'm getting now only one-lined string, not a table (only that part of code which shows status of many DB's on specific server)

Comment: I'm aware what your problem is and I'm telling you to run a damn replace because you're sending **HTML** and that string doesn't have **HTML line breaks** but instead just regular ones which aren't relevant for **HTML**. You need to run a replace on your `$output`. Alternatively don't send HTML.

Comment: Aaaaaaa, you right! I didn't get it until now. This line which I mentioned is producing a string which contains line breaks standard for powershell such as `"'n"`. So, I need to take this output and do something like `$output.replace("'n", "<br />")` Sorry for not understanding it quick enough :/

Answer (score 0):

Try gather all data into an array, then use ConvertTo-HTML cmdlet, and the 'BodyAsHTML' switch in Send-MailMessage

```
$DatabaseArray=@()

ForEach ($server in $list) {
     $srv = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" $server
     $DatabaseArray += $srv.Databases | Where-Object {$_.IsMirroringEnabled -eq $true} | Select-Object Name,MirroringStatus   
}

$HTMLBody = $DatabaseArray | ConvertTo-HTML

Send-MailMessage -subject x -body $HTMLBody -BodyAsHTML
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using this method I'm getting error:
`Send-MailMessage : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Body'. Określona metoda nie jest obsługiwana.` - last sentence translated: The specified method is not supported